# asp:dropdownlist is null on page_load

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, drop-down-menu

I have an ascx control;

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LanguageSelect.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyNamespace.LanguageSelect" %>
```

with code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Languages = GetSiteLanguagesService();
            if (Languages.Count > 1)
            {

                //null reference exception here!! languageDropdown is null!
                LanguageDropdown.Visible = true;
                LanguageDropdown.DataTextField = "DisplayName";
                LanguageDropdown.DataValueField = "LangUrl";
                LanguageDropdown.DataSource = Languages ;
                LanguageDropdown.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

inside another control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SomePage.ascx.cs" Inherits="myNamespace.SomePage" %>
<div id="main" role="main"> 
    <myTag:LanguageSelect id="langSelect" runat="server" />
    <div class="section columns"> 
        <div class="main-column"> ....
```

With the debugger i hit on the page_load of `LanguageSelect`, but the dropdown is null! if i'm adding the drop down control in the markup, i thought it should always exists, in this case it is behaving like it was just a dynamic control..

now, the control SomePage is being rendered in the html, but this one in the `myTag` is not being rendered at all, does not matter if i wrap the dropdown list in a div, the div won't be rendered either!!

If i put the breakpoint in the `SomePage` page_load, the langSelect control will be there (not null), but it itself has a null LanguageDropdown

Comment: Is your UserControl added dynamically to the page? I'm asking because people sometimes to forget that they must create an instance of it via `Page.LoadControl` instead of using the constructor. Side-Note: It's almost always a bad idea to use page events to inititialize the UserControl implicitely. Instead the controller(normally the page) should initialize the control directly(f.e. via calling a method `BindData` or `Init`). Otherwise it can lead to lifecycle issue and unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: @TimSchmelter no, its not added dynamically, well... if the control is being added as markup it means is NOT dynamical right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, figured out the problem; when the control is embedded in other control, ASP.NET assumes that you will override rendering (it will not render the sub-controls automatically)

I had to made the following changes to Page_Load, basically allocating the control:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Languages = GetSiteLanguagesService();
            if (Languages.Count > 1)
            {

                LanguageDropdown = new DropDownList(); //allocate the control
                LanguageDropdown.Visible = true;
                LanguageDropdown.DataTextField = "DisplayName";
                LanguageDropdown.DataValueField = "LangUrl";
                LanguageDropdown.DataSource = Languages ;
                LanguageDropdown.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

and then, add an override for the OnRender handler:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            base.Render(writer);
            LanguageDropdown.RenderControl(writer);
        }
```

After this, the control rendered perfectly!

Comment: I think you should say "When the control inherits from another control" and not "when the control is embedded in another control". They are two completely different things.

Comment: @rperson i don't understand; `LangSelect` does not inherit from `SomePage`, it is *embedded in it*

Answer (score 5):

1. Is your UserControl added dynamically to the page? I'm asking because people sometimes to forget that they must create an instance of it via [`Page.LoadControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcontrol.aspx) instead of using the constructor.
2. Have you registered the UserControl in the page?

For example:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="Lang" Src="controls/LanguageSelect.ascx" %>
```

Side-note: It's almost always a bad idea to use page events to inititialize the `UserControl` implicitely. Instead the controller(normally the page) should initialize the control directly(via calling a method like `BindData` or `Init`). 
Otherwise it can lead to lifecycle issues or nasty errors.

Comment: well, the user control itself is a sitecore sublayout

Comment: what bothers is that it even doesn't matter that the control is dynamical or not (and its not), because if i allocate the LanguageDropdown and try to add it to the page i would get an error because i cannot modify page on the load, init, render events

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the auto-generated ".ascx.designer.cs" file and regenerate it. To do this, follow the steps:

- delete the .ascx.*.designer.cs
- right-click the ascx file and select "Convert to Web Application"

Now the designer.cs file is recreated. See if the things are gonna work now.

Comment: didn't work, and the designer.cs seems in sync with the markup anyway

Answer (score 1):

It might be trying to load your `UserControl` (.ascx) as a `CustomControl` (no .ascx). Check your page and web.config pages/controls section for references to `LanguageSelect`'s namespace instead of the .ascx path.